# Table alias in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

I have the following to find posts.

```
@posts = Post.find(:all, 
:select => "DISTINCT *",
:include => [:user, {:track => :artist}],
:conditions => ["user_id IN (?) AND NOT track_id = ?", users, @track.id],
:group => "track_id", 
:order => 'id desc', 
:limit => '5')
```

I would like to add the subselect

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts P2 
    WHERE P2.user_id = P1.user_id AND P2.id > P1.id AND P2.track_id <> 34)
 <= 1
```

in my conditions clause, to restrict the number of posts per user.

How do I set the alias P1 to the "initial" posts table?

Using rails 2.3.11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a `from` parameter:

```
:from => 'posts P1',
```

[find (ActiveRecord::Base)](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class)